# Double variable with 16+ digits gives error: Integer Number too Large

Tags: java

The following code is designed to factorize a number typed into the variable x.

```
public class testMod{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        double x = 11868681080091051216000;
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("1 * ");
        for(double y = 2; y <= x; y++){
            while (x % y == 0) {
                System.out.print("Calculating... \n");
                String printNumber = y + " * ";
                x = x / y;
                output.append(printNumber);
                System.out.print(output.substring(0, output.length() - 2) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ..Use `BigInteger`

Comment: It's just what it has said. The number is too large for `double`. Consider using `BigInteger`.

Comment: Also,  you might want to check that your double hasn't lost precision in the process. I think doubles are fine as long as the value is in the range, but it can change the value. So... start with a big integer too.

Comment: The issue isn't that it's too large for `double`, but that it's an `int` literal which is out of range. If it were within the range of `long` then you could append an `L` to the literal, but it's too big for that too.

Comment: It's not that `11868681080091051216000` is too large to be represented (approximately) as a double, it's too large to be a 32-bit integer.  It seems that Java is baulking at the *rhs* of the assignment, ie before it even tries to assign the value to `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler treats `11868681080091051216000` as an `int`, regardless of the attempt to assign it to a `double`. As such, it's out of range.

To specify a `double` literal, you can simply append `D` to the end – but do note that you'll lose precision this way:

```
double x = 11868681080091051216000D;
System.out.println(x); // prints 186868108009105E22
```

If you need the full precision, you can use a `BigInteger` instead, but you'll still need to specify that number in expressions that Java can handle, such as a [product of its factors](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factors+of+11868681080091051216000).

Comment: So there is no way to keep the accuracy of the number without changing the type of the variable?

Comment: The `long` and `double` data types are both 64 bits wide. The number is larger than 2^64, so there simply isn't any way to precisely represent it using those types. It's like trying to represent the number 1,234,567,890 on an 8-digit calculator display.